# iis website windows.location.href = (“/xx”) forward dosnt work but "./xx" or even no slash works

Tags: visual-studio, iis

Why does my `window.location.href = ('/MbsaExercise/MobileExerciseDescriptionMaint?mode=Init');` work in my mvc visual studio 2017 iis web site, but i get 404 when I access the same project from an iis default web site application when I try to access my development desktop from my cell phone for development testing?

it looks like when i replace `('/MbsaExercise` with (no slash) `('MbsaExercise` or replace `('/MbsaExercise` with (a dot) `('./MbsaExercise` then the page is successfully called up.

I thought about the url rewrite, but, after looking at my code i see other situations where i am building a url and it seems like i have to figure out a way to url rewrite those.

after looking around, it seems like i need to use the url rewrite to take care of this, but is it my only option? are there other things i might consider? like some kind of way to use ISAPI filters perhaps.

I don’t understand why debug from visual studio 2017 works with this window.location.href situation, but it dosnt work from my phone in this development mode. ALSO, I can access this application from my production server just fine from my phone and a desktop web browser.

thanks for your time and advice.

Comment: When you put your project on the server, are you putting it in the root of the server?

Comment: tgolisch, thanks for getting back. My project is in iis like this: in the edit application feature i have "Alias = mbsa17", "Application pool = MbsaWebSite17 "Physical path = C:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2017", In advanced settings feature i have "virtual path = /mbsa17". so, i dont have my project in wwwroot, if that is what i think you are asking?

Comment: on my phone and in fiddler, the host is "192.168.x.x" the URL is "/mbsa17/" but on my phone, when i use windows.location.href, i loose the virtual root which is /mbsa17/", when it loses this virtual root, then it shows "/content/images/help.jpg" instead of "192.168.x.x/mbsa17//content/images/help.jpg"??
my phone is looking into my laptop dev box.
I meant "192.168.x.x/mbsa17/content/images/help.jpg" (one forward slash)
my virtual root "/mbsa17" seems to get lost when i use jquery to build a URL path. otherwise,

Comment: when i run my project under visual studio whose virtual directory is really a website in IIS, it runs fine??
"/content/images/help.jpg" shows as 404
sorry to be so verbose
to keep things in perspective, my visual studio project is a website under IIS, and my phone is trying to connect to an application under the IIS Default web site. i am using the 192.168.x.x on my phone which is connected to my laptop network by wifi.

Comment: The physical HDD location is irrelevant. What is relevant is the relation between your app (on IIS) and the IIS root.  In VStudio, every app runs in the root.  If you don't deploy it to your server the same way, then the difference will cause a problem like you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, your project always runs in the root, by default. On your IIS server, it looks like you are running your project in a sub-folder called `/mbsa17/`.  Therefore, all of your url references *must* use relative paths (no absolute paths like `/MbaExercise/somewebpage`), because the `/` at the beginning means "from the root of the server".  You need `./` meaning "relative to the current path" or `~/` meaning "relative to the root of my project". To make things simple, I usually use `~/` everywhere that I would have used `/`.

Comment: sorry, i had to go out of town for the last 3 weeks. i think i get your point, but under the current IIS configuration i believe, the "~/" tilde does not work in my scenario. but what you said about " (no absolute paths like /MbaExercise/somewebpage)" makes sense. this "/MbaExercise/somewebpage" works through visual studio, but not when i try to get there using my mobile phone to access my VS project in visual studio?

Comment: If this is the correct answer, could you please mark it as "answered".  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to access "window.location.href" from my android phone to my laptop AND, for some IIS configurations in visual studio, I was getting 404's.

I was using the forward slash ('/MbsaExercise) like this:
window.location.href = ('/MbsaExercise/MobileExerciseDescriptionMaint?mode=Create');

I took the forward slash out ('MbsaExercise) of all of the "window.location.href" like this 
 "window.location.href = ('MbsaExercise/MobileExerciseDescriptionMaint?mode=Create');"
 after testing the removed forward slash in the major browsers and on my production machine as well. Yep, had to change 50 or so files, but it went quick. I consider this as my answer.

it took me several weeks to try to use and configure my app in IIS. if anyone 
ever finds a way to use this forward slash with "window.location.href", within IIS, please let me know.

also, FYI, using "./" also seemed to work like this:
window.location.href = ('./MbsaExercise/MobileExerciseDescriptionMaint?mode=Create');